# How can 'Literal' be invoked with square brackets (e.g. Literal["Test1"])?

Tags: python

The following code snippet shows a function named `Literal` being invoked with square brackets:

```
Literal['r', 'rb', 'w', 'wb']
```

The example is from [the CPython GitHub repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/typing.py#L728)

Though we can use square brackets to call instances by using `__getitem__` method in Python classes, it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: `Literal` is not a function or a method.

Comment: @juanpa I imagine OP needs some explanation *why* that is, given the source code linked above…

Comment: @deceze Oops you're right. Reopened the question then.

Comment: `Literal` returns an instance of `_LiteralGenericAlias` class which does implement the `__getitem__`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM The question is what triggers a call to `Literal` in the first place, not what it returns from a call.

Comment: @blhsing oh my bad, Thanks for the correction. It seems that' being done by this [decorator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4afa7be32da32fac2a2bcde4b881db174e81240c/Lib/typing.py#L2032)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the source code there are these decorators

```py
@_TypedCacheSpecialForm # this is a class
@_tp_cache(typed=True) # not relevant here
def Literal(self, *parameters):
   ...
```

`_TypedCacheSpecialForm` is a class, when using a class a decorator the function, here `def Literal`, is used to initialize an instance.
Written differently you could write:

```
Literal = _TypedCacheSpecialForm(lambda self, *parameters: ...)

# or 

def _literal_function(self, *parameters):
   ... #contents of def Literal

Literal = _TypedCacheSpecialForm(_literal_function)
```

In short: **Literal is a instance of a class which has a `__getitem__` method**. With the call to `__getitem__` `Literal._getitem` is invoked, which is the *actual* function declared as `def Literal` in the source code.
`Literal[str] -> __getitem__(str) -> _getitem(str)/def Literal(str)` returns then an instance of the `_LiteralGenericAlias` class. Which you could say is the actual type hint.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a function or method; it is a type annotation.

Probably read https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html for an overview of the concepts.

Quoting [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/),

> The square brackets mean that no new syntax needs to be added to the language.

In other words, the type annotations are basically overriding the subscript notation to add information to types which require subtype information or other metainformation.

The PEP in fact reveals that this is using `__getitem__` under the hood, and provides multiple implementation examples.